# Lift of a Riemannian metric to the cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-mechanics

Let us have a Riemmanian manifold $(M,g)$. Is there some “natural“/canonical way to lift the metric to the cotangent bundle $T^* M$, i.e. define a metric on $T^*M$?

I ask because I have read some articles on orthogonal separation of variables (on configuration space) heavily using Killing tensors and other notions from Riemannian geometry and I am thinking whether it can be extended to separation on the phase space of Hamiltonian mechanics.

Comment: What do you mean by "lift?" There are two ways to interpret your question: one is that you want to define a Riemannian metric on the total space of the cotangent bundle, the other is that you want to define a contravariant tensor on the original manifold (raising indices of the original metric tensor). Both are possible and quite standard.

Comment: I mean the first - defining the metric on $T^*M$.

Comment: As far as I know the closest thing to a "standard" riemannian metric on $T^*M$ is the [Sasaki Metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasaki_metric). It's usually constructed on $TM$ but a similar set of conditions define an analogous metric on $T^*M$.

Comment: @Kajelad thanks for the comment. So it can be done, but is by definition transversal to the fibres, so it will not be compatible with symplectic structure. So the idea behind the question is probably misguided.